# What's with all the spaghetti?

Tags: discussion, questions

Overnight, FIFTEEN questions about spaghetti parties popped up. What is going on? Is it national spaghetti day? Are we changing out name to Spaghetti-Puzzling.Stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yesterday I asked [What's the password, again?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/whats-the-password-again) because it felt like a nice follow-on to [the first password puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2497/whats-the-password) (I think it's the first, anyhow). It seems that some other people saw the number sequence japes and decided to join in the fun like I had, and it quickly spiralled out of control.

I actually think it's a positive sign, because people are clearly interested in creating puzzles and original content is what the site needs. It might be a bit rough with the spaghetti parties now (so many parties, so few days to partay), but hopefully it'll spread out into all kinds of interesting puzzles.

At least we have enough spaghetti to last through the winter.

Comment: It would be a positive sign if the questions came at a more relaxed pace and not fifteen in the span of seven hours. This is like code-trolling at PCG.SE all over again, but accelerated tenfold.

Comment: @JoeZ. it looks like interest in them is waning though: p1 has 800 views, p2 has 500, then a couple of others have 400, everything else is <150 views.

Comment: True. I'm just saying I wouldn't consider it a "positive sign" at all.

Comment: Yeah, in the future to anyone who reads this, it's great that you're enthusiastic about the site (honestly!), but please do try to adopt a more moderate pace.

Comment: I have no idea what the code-trolling at PCG.SE was.  But each of these spaghetti party puzzles is an independent puzzle, so does it really matter if 15 show up within a few hours?  It really wouldn't be any different than if 15 completely different types of puzzles were posted in a few hours.

Comment: @Emrakul: If new users are creating original puzzles then what (other than [NIH syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)) can possibly be wrong about that?

Comment: @AE If people find it disruptive, then the easy solution is to just delay posting a little. I'm not suggesting new users don't post, but perhaps refrain from posting eight or ten questions at once.

Comment: @Emrakul: I don't see any one new user posting eight or ten questions. I **do** see hostility from existing high-rep users towards new users. Being unwelcoming to newbies is no way to get the site out of beta.

Comment: Hasn't this specific spaghetti thing gone overboard? I mean, we're at 29 questions as of now, and after the first 5 or so they all drop off to about 150 views. Now (the day after the 2014 Spaghetti Surge) the new fad is "What am I?" puzzles. Granted, they're all original, but they're taking over the website almost. I for one am against it.

Comment: Yes, the site needs original content, but it also needs variety in its content. If the first 10 questions which a first-time visitor sees are all people jumping on one bandwagon, the message that communicates is that this is a site where people *lack* originality and creativity.

Comment: If they were all the same then I agree that would be dull. Where people are using other members' puzzles as a jumping-off point, I'm really enjoying that. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/security-to-the-party-27-conspiracy-edition is a good example. Just because the setup is the same, that doesn't mean that the merit of the puzzle (or even the type of the puzzle) is the same. [Influence / parody is a normal part of finding an original voice in any creative genre](http://www.todayszaman.com/arts-culture_harold-bloom-influence-is-just-another-word-for-literature_261998.html).

Comment: @Joe For what it's worth, it was me who caused the code-trolling tag to spiral into doom by [posting the second question of its type](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16327/how-do-i-find-the-longest-palindrome-in-a-string). We all make mistakes.

Answer (score 11):

Believe it's called 'enthusiasm' and possibly even 'community'.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :-) I just tried to create a 'party-security' tag on puzzling.SE, but for some reason it doesn't come up.

Comment: @randal'thor: thanks. 'party-security' tag is mod-deleted. We're meant to use 'password' instead.

Comment: OK, fair enough. This explains why my 'party-security' tag changed itself to 'password'.